# scrollbar does not appear in my html page

Tags: css

When I add an element after the page is full the element cant show because no scrollbar.

I tried `overflow:auto` , and `overflow:scroll` but it doesn't work!

My goal is to show the footer elements but the scrollbar is not shown.

Here is my style sheet code:

```
body
{
    background-color:#fae4ef;

}

img {
    width: 200px; height: 150px;

}
div.image {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: left;  
}
p.s1{
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-family: 'Arial Nova';
}
#h1style {
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-family:   'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
p.s2{
    margin-left: 475px;
}
p.s3{
    margin-left:15px;
    font-family:  'AGA Arabesque';
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #97cfb6;
    position:absolute;
    top: 125px;    
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 112px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Verdana", arial, sans-serif;

}

.active {
    background-color: #fa82b2;
    text-decoration-color:antiquewhite;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: I’m very Sorry but I can’t if you want to explain any style please let me know thanks

Comment: I understand what you mean by each style, but I must see your HTML to know **what are you using each style for**. Sharing CSS without HTML is like using with a screwdriver but with no screws.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: A) you dont have to show your "real" HTML here. Just something that is good enough to show your problem. B) "doesnt work" isn't a helpful problem description.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the **float**s.
But it's really difficult to help you without seeing the code structure, that's why it is important to see the HTML.

I'd recommend if you have any confidential data or something in your HTML, that you change it for some fake data and share the structure so we can really help. :)